# How to make an object deeply readonly

Tags: c++, constants

How can I make a class, which is sometimes readonly, and sometimes writable? One option is with getter/setters and a flag which indicates if the object is read-only, but that is a lot of overhead. I also desire this readonly property to work deeply on the object, making sure that all of the objects it contains are also readonly or writeable. Here's some example code of the desired behavior which I tried but failed to achieve using const.

This question is quite generic, so has probably been asked before, but I wasn't able to find a good solution to this exact problem on stackoverflow.

Example code:
https://ideone.com/4cXyNF

```
class InnerClass {
 public:
  InnerClass(int j) : j_(j) {}
  int j_;
};

class OuterClass {
 public:
  OuterClass(int i, InnerClass& c) : i_(i), reference_(c), pointer_(&c) {}
  int i_;
  InnerClass& reference_;
  InnerClass* pointer_;
};

int main() {
    InnerClass c(1);

    OuterClass readwrite(2, c);
    // Desire these 3 operations to work on the writable object
    readwrite.i_ = 3;
    readwrite.reference_.j_ = 4;
    readwrite.pointer_->j_ = 5;

    const OuterClass readonly(6, c);
    // COMPILER ERROR: error: assignment of member 'OuterClass::i_'
    // in read-only object
    // readonly.i_ = 7;
    // Desire this to be a compiler error, but it isn't
    readonly.reference_.j_ = 8;
    // Desire this to be a compiler error, but it isn't
    readonly.pointer_->j_ = 9;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well the reason it does not result in a compile error is because you **aren't** modifying the pointer or the reference (those values still point to the same thing)....I think you might be able to use a templated solution (I would have to think about that a little more though)

Comment: Instead of asking how to do this particular thing, could you explain what you're really trying to achieve?   What you're asking is quite difficult to do, and it's likely that your underlying requirement actually has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your members to functions, you can create const overloads of the methods like this

```
class InnerClass {
public:

  explicit
  InnerClass(int j) : j_(j) {}

  int& j() { return j_; }
  const int& j() const { return j_; } 
private:
  int j_;
};

class OuterClass {
public:

  OuterClass(int i, InnerClass& c) : i_(i), reference_(c), pointer_(&c) {}

  int& i() { return i_; }
  const int& i() const { return i_; } 

  InnerClass const& reference() const { return reference_; };
  InnerClass & reference()  { return reference_; };

  InnerClass const* pointer() const { return pointer_; };
  InnerClass * pointer() { return pointer_; };

private:
  int i_;

  InnerClass& reference_;
  InnerClass* pointer_;
};

int main() {
    InnerClass c(1);

    OuterClass readwrite(2, c);
    // Desire these 3 operations to work on the writable object
    readwrite.i() = 3;
    readwrite.reference().j() = 4;
    readwrite.pointer()->j() = 5;

    const OuterClass readonly(6, c);
    // COMPILER ERROR: error: assignment of member 'OuterClass::i_'
    // in read-only object
    readonly.i_ = 7;
    // Desire this to be a compiler error, and it is
    readonly.reference().j() = 8;
    // Desire this to be a compiler error, and it is
    readonly.pointer()->j() = 9;

    return 0;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8575fb773ad69a0)</kbd>**

Comment: This is the same solution as Pixelchemist wrote, and has the same problems I commented on there. Namely, it doesn't work if there is also an InnerInnerClass and InnerClass has a pointer to it, and I do not have the ability to modify the signature of InnerClass because I do not own that code and it is part of a library I am using.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using member functions to return the references / pointers `const` if the object itself is `const`.

```
class InnerClass {
 public:
  InnerClass(int j) : j_(j) {}
  int j_;
};

class OuterClass
{
  InnerClass& reference_;
public:
  OuterClass(int i, InnerClass& c) : i_(i), reference_(c) {}
  int i_;
  InnerClass & in() { return reference_; }
  InnerClass const & in() const { return reference_; }
};
```

Now neither `i_` nor `in().j_` is writable in case `outer` is `const`:

```
InnerClass i{ 1 };
OuterClass write(2, i);
write.i_ = 3; // works
write.in().j_ = 3; // works
OuterClass const read(2, i);
read.i_ = 3; // error!
read.in().j_ = 3; // error!
```

Comment: This is quite close! The only problem is this relies on me being able to modify the interfaces of all the classes in the entire object tree. Imagine there is an InnerInnerClass, and I don't have permission to modify the interface of InnerClass as someone else owns that code.

Comment: @AffluentOwl: The interface of `inner` is not touched. It is the interface of `outer` that has changed (reference to inner gone private and two accessor functions added where one is `const` and the other is not).

Comment: I'm saying to assume that these class definitions are recursive. So imagine that InnerClass had 2 members `InnerInnerClass& reference_` and `InnerInnerClass* pointer_` that I also desired to be readonly.

Comment: @AffluentOwl: If it is indeed some kind of recusion (linked list or something) then changing one interface is enough. If it is not - that's unfortunate and I'd consider it to be suboptimal design. The constness of a class can only directly restrict access to its very own members and not to whatever they may point or refer. The idea of having "a class that has a public reference member to a class that has a public reference member to a class that has..." sprung from a const-correctness nightmare, I'm sure. ;-)

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive, just assume there are 3 levels of classes. But I cannot modify `InnerClass` or `InnerInnerClass` because I do not own that code and inherit them from a library from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar solution as some else already posted, but uses a slightly different approach:

```
class InnerClass {
 public:
  InnerClass(int j) : j_(j) {}
  int j_;
};

template<bool readOnly>
class OuterClass{
 public:
  OuterClass(int i, InnerClass& c) : i_(i), reference_(c), pointer_(&c) {}
  int i_;
  typename std::conditional<readOnly,const InnerClass&, InnerClass&>::type reference_;
  typename std::conditional<readOnly,const InnerClass* const, InnerClass*>::type pointer_;
};

int main(int argc,char** args){
    InnerClass c(1);
    OuterClass<true> readonly(12,c);
    //readonly.reference_.j_ = 1;   //Error "reference_ is read only"
    //readonly.pointer_->j_ = 1;    //Error "pointer_ is read only"
    OuterClass<false> write(12,c);
    write.reference_.j_ = 1;
    write.pointer_->j_ = 1;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Unfortunately, this has the same problem as Pixelchemist's answer in that it doesn't work recursively if we have a InnerInnerClass and assume the same with pointers and references inside InnerClass if someone else wrote InnerClass and I am not able to change its signature.

Comment: @AffluentOwl If you don't have control of the declaration of the references and/or pointers I don't know if their **is** anything you can do....at least not that I can see